# Using terser webpack plugin how to avoid building with comments

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using the terser webpack plugin. I tried with this configuration.

```
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: false,
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
```

But still, it outputs a .LICENSE file. How to build the code without comments.

Answer (score 7):

Should be

```
new TerserPlugin({
    extractComments: false,
})
```

see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#extractcomments

Comment: This sure should work, according to the docs, but it doesn't work for me. My build still writes license files, which we aren't using and don't need. They just clutter things up for us. My other terser param setting works but this one does not. Weird.

Comment: If you have trouble with extractComments option, make sure that you place it outside the terserOptions object. It will not work and there is no error message if you place it inside the terserOptions object.

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#remove-comments) also give an example for "if you avoid building with comments":

```
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          format: {
            comments: false,
          },
        },
        extractComments: false,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

**Note:** Both the `extractComments: false` and `terserOptions: { format: { comments: false } }` options are used.

Answer (score 1):

With boolean terser will try to produce some licence comments and .txt files:

```
extractComments: false,
```

This solution works for me:

```
new TerserPlugin({
  extractComments: (astNode, comment) => false,
})
```

[Webpack terser documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#extractcomments)